# Javascript CSS deleteRule property

Tags: javascript, css

Hey I'm trying to figure out why deleteRule isn't working for my css object in javascript. I made a very simple test to illustrate.
http://codepen.io/wzsun/pen/uzcvI

```
console.log(cssRule.cssRules.length); <-- returns 2
cssRule.deleteRule(1); // <-- can't delete
cssRule.insertRule("to { -webkit-transform: rotatex(360deg); background-color:blue;}") // <-- this works
console.log(cssRule.cssRules.length); <-- returns 3
console.log(cssRule);
cssRule.deleteRule(2);
```

I can insert a rule but I can't delete one. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you try to manually `.splice()` the array property? This seems like an interesting problem. +1

Comment: I did not, will look into it, I just started testing the CSSOM with javascript.

Comment: `cssRule.deleteRule(0);` works?

Comment: nope, it does not work

Comment: What exactly is `cssRule`?

Comment: It just holds the CSS object I want to edit, in this case its a @keyframe object.

Comment: Ah, I checked your codepen, it's a [`CSSKeyframesRule`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSKeyframesRule) to be explicit. Notice that you're calling `removeRule()` there instead of `deleteRule()`

Comment: I was trying some other stuff out to see if anything would work. Although the deleteRule still doesnt work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have got intrested by the problem you shown and I think I found the answer. If you want to call removeRule you have to remove rule by attribute DOMString key

```
void            deleteRule(in DOMString key);
```

and its value between 0 and 1 (for example 0%, 50%, 100%). Thats why index passed didnt worked.

> [CSSKeyframe.keyText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSKeyframeRule) Represents the key of the keyframe, like '10%',
>   '75%'. The from keyword maps to '0%' and the to keyword maps to '100%'

[CSSKeyframesRule MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSKeyframesRule)

What you have to do is to find a keyText ( [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772378(v=vs.85).aspx), [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSKeyframeRule) ) and then simply use it to deleteRule()

```
keyToRemove = cssRule.cssRules[1].keyText;
console.log(cssRule);
console.log(cssRule.cssRules.length);
cssRule.deleteRule(keyToRemove);
```

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/scx/eMWXE/1/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm newone so I just want to attach to scx answer but I can not, so I create this answer like a continued.

I'll just add that if someone has, for example rule with 14.5% this should write 0.145.

`cssRule.deleteRule(0.145);`

Unfortunately, there is a rounding problem if you have ***xx.xx%*** two decimal places, so be careful.