# Hybrid mobile app developed with IBM MobileFirst Platform v7.1 (incl. Dojo Toolkit SDK 1.10.3) crashes after upgrading to iOS 10.3

Tags: javascript, css, ibm-mobilefirst, dojox.mobile, ios10.3

I have a hybrid mobile app developed with IBM MobileFirst Platform v7.1 with Dojo mobile. After upgrading to iOS 10.3 the app crashes every time when a user scrolls. I believe the problem is related to dojo Scrollable View. Crash report says "WebCore: WebCore::StyleRuleKeyframes::findKeyframeIndex(WTF::String const&) const + 80". Do you have any ideas what can be the reason of this crash or what I can try to do in order to identify and fix this problem? The app works normally on other iOS versions and on Android as well.

---

It is clear with this part now (see answer below). Now the question is if '0' is the same as '0%', why there was such a code at the first place?

Comment: Can try your application with only dojo (without MFP) and test?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I don't think that it is possible, because dojo mobile comes with MFP and it is used in javascript part that is connected with native parts by MFP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with deleteRule function inside mobile-ui-layer.js dojo file.

This does not work on iOS 10.3:

```
c.deleteRule(m("webkit") ? "from" : 0);
```

This works:

```
c.deleteRule("from");
```

Comment: This is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24726725/javascript-css-deleterule-property