# Why is not only the pseudo-class removed, and the entire css document is deleted?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
var ter = document.styleSheets[1]  

ter.deleteRule(`.block__header::after`)

console.log(`.block__header::after`)
```

Why does not it remove it from the css document?

In the console finds this pseudo-class, if run through the loop deletes all css of the document.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
     ter.deleteRule(`.block__header::after`)
}
```

Comment: please elaborate your problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript CSS deleteRule property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24726725/javascript-css-deleterule-property)

Comment: We can't help you with this information what you provide. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Method deleteRule takes an index as a parameter. Look in the docs: [deleteRule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/deleteRule). Here you have an example how to do this: [Remove CSS rules by JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29927992/remove-css-rules-by-javascript)